# Collision only works 2 sides

Tags: c#, collision-detection

So i am trying to make a pacman clone in c#, Visual studio express 2013. I have the maze, and ive put labels on the edges. I have a point with the future coordinates of pacman. If that point doesnt intersect with the labels, pacmans location will take the location of the point. This works just fine when pacman is comming from down or right, however it doesnt work if he comes from right or top. This is also true for the ghosts, whose movement is randomly generated. They both seem to consider the label bigger. I tried to search the internet for why this might be, but i cant seem to find an answer. Ive put down the part with collision check and pacman movement. Thanks in advance

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //colision check
        PictureBox intermed = new PictureBox
        {
            Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + pacdirx, pictureBox1.Location.Y + pacdiry),
        };
        if (!intermed.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label1.Bounds) )
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + pacdirx, pictureBox1.Location.Y + pacdiry);

    private void Form3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //pacman movement
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {

            pacdiry = -3;
            pacdirx = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("eat_up.gif");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            pacdiry = 3;
            pacdirx = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("eat_down.gif");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            pacdiry = 0;
            pacdirx = 3;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("eat_right.gif");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            pacdiry = 0;
            pacdirx = -3;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("eat_left.gif");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never set the size of `intermed`, so it's going to be the default size (100x50). Also, there's no reason to create the picture box in the first place - just use  a `Rectangle` with the proper size.